# Flutter Wrap widget: grouping content widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to be able to group say a `Text` widget and a `Radio` widget so that when I place them in a `Wrap` widget (along with a number of other widgets), should the `Radio` component need to be wrapped to the next line/row, then it is not separated from the `Text` widget and both of them are moved to the next row/line together.

How can that be achieved in Flutter please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using the `Wrap` widget, you can group your `Text` and `Radio` inside a `Row` Widget to keep them always together.

You also need to give `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to your `Row` widget in order to let other widgets render beside it.

```
Wrap(           
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Sample text', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
    Text('Sample text', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
    Text('Sample text', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
    Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Radio(value: true, groupValue: true),
        Text('Radio Title', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
      ],
    ),
    Text('Sample text', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly; super star. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped :D